# Проблема с БД при выгрузке сайта на хостинг

Tags: php, sql, хостинг

На локалке сайт работал отлично всё выводилось, но когда я выгрузил сайт на хостинг, то вся БД полетела. Я посмотрел в гугле, сказали добавить проверку

```
$elems1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT DISTINCT `third_name` FROM `category`");
                            if(is_array($elems1)){
                            foreach ($elems1 as $i1 => $elem1) { ?>
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <span class="toggle-child"><i class="fa fa-plus plus"></i><i class="fa fa-minus minus"></i></span>
                                    <a href="category.php?id=<?= $i1 ?>&ct=third_id" class="parent-link dropdown-img"><?= $elem1['third_name'] ?><i class="fa fa-angle-down arrow"></i></a>
```

До этой проверки была ошибка "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/u1717127/data/www/u1717127.isp.regruhosting.ru/index.php on line 739", после ввода проверки ошибка исчезла, но из БД товары не загружаются на сайт, там просто пусто в месте где должны выгружаться товары.

Comment: как выгружаешь через amiadmin?

Comment: `mysqli_query` никогда не возвращает массив, написанная проверка не проверяет ничего путного.